# If $p\leq q$ then $pq=p$ where p and q are projections in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

This is from Murphy's C*algebra textbook:
[image]

I am trying to understand why 5) implies 2) because the submultiplicative inequality only goes one way. So we have $||p(1-q)||\leq ||p||||(1-q)|| \leq ||q||||1-q||$. But from here , we do not have that $||q||||1-q||\leq ||q(1-q)||$ so how do we get the final inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y= (1-q)(x)$, then we get, using $(5)$

$$ \Vert p(1-q)(x) \Vert = \Vert p (y) \Vert \leq \Vert q(y) \Vert
= \Vert q (1-q)(x) \Vert = \Vert (q-q^2)(x) \Vert. $$

Answer (score 0):

If $q(x)=0,$ then $p(x)=0.$ As $q(I-q)=0$ then  $p(I-q)=0.$

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way of looking at this: the inequality $\|px\|\leq \|qx\|$ can be written, after squaring and using that $p,q$ are projections, as
$$
\langle px,x\rangle\leq\langle qx,x\rangle. 
$$
As this works of all $x$, this means that $p\leq q$, which is condition $(1)$.  To obtain $(2)$, we can multiply on the left and right by $1-q$, to get
$$
0\leq(1-q)p(1-q)\leq (1-q)q(1-q)=0.
$$
So $(1-q)p(1-q)=0$. As this can be written as
$$
0=\big[p(1-q)\big]^*\,p(1-q),
$$
we get that $p(1-q)=0$.